# Calling other form method

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 form, Form 1 and 2. Form 1 will be used to initialize Form 2. After Form 2 being  initialize, Form 2 will be calling Form 1 method but it just won't work. I had been searching for hours but still no idea how it works. Please help me out.

Form 1

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace parentChildTest
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {

             public Form1()
             {
                 InitializeComponent();
             }

             private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
             {
                 Form2 x = new Form2();
                 x.Show();
             }

             public static void callMe(){
                 MessageBox.Show("HAHAHA");
             }
        }
    }
```

Form 2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace parentChildTest
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            /*How to call callMe()?????*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to initialize form1 again. Just call the function with its class name. Static methods can be called with the class name directly.

Comment: Your problem will become slightly more complicated when you want to remove `static` from `callMe`, but there is plenty of research material that should be able to assist you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.Callme();
    }
}
```

Comment: `callMe` is static, so why do you need to create a new instance?

Comment: static methods can be called without an object.

Comment: I want to continue to use my old initialized Form1. Not the new one

Comment: Sorry guys....I'm so blur just now.............It's works now for sure. Thanks for waking me up. I didn't notice it's already the correct one.

Comment: If you want to use the Instance of form1, pass it into form2 constructor, save the instance as a variable, and then call the method on the reference

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1.callMe();
}
```